# Qt executes an event before another event finishes its execution

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a project, which is a C++/Qt desktop application. In this application, I've identified a certain problem related to the execution of interface events.

For example, in this application, the mousePressEvent delegates a certain operation to the program, and this operation can be slow sometimes, so if the user presses the mouse button before this operation ends, the program begins to execute another operation before the previous one finishes.

Does anyone ever have this same issue with Qt?

Thank you.

Comment: It should not do this because the GUI is single threaded and you can not interact with the GUI directly from any other thread.

Comment: Without seeing the code all we can do is guess.  But it sounds like you're returning control to the Qt event loop from within the mouse button press event handler -- via a `QEventLoop` or `QCoreApplication::processEvents` call etc.  If that's the case then this is just something you have to deal with.

Comment: Got it, I will verify this. Thank you!